# Enumerable Properties JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a question.
When I use the for...in loop over a Nodelist for example I receive enumerable properties such as entries,keys,values..
These properties are from the NodeList Object which means i could test the enumerability with `NodeList.propertyIsEnumerable("keys");`
Why do I get a false in return?
Thanks for your help.
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

> which means i could test the enumerability with `NodeList.propertyIsEnumerable("keys");`

No, `NodeList` is a function, which doesn't have the `keys` property. If you want to know if the property is an enumerable property on the prototype of `NodeList` instances, you'd want to use `NodeList.prototype`, not `NodeList`:

```js
console.log(NodeList.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable("keys"));
// true (at least on Chromium-based browsers)
```

---

Originally I thought the `NodeList` part of your question was notional, a stand-in for a **specific** node list (rather than the `NodeList` function). But `someNodeList.propertyIsEnumerabe("keys")` would also return `false`, because [`propertyIsEnumerable`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.propertyisenumerable) only returns `true` for **own** enumerable properties, and `keys` is an inherited property:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll("*");
console.log(`list.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")? ${list.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")}`);
// => list.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")? false
console.log(`Object.hasOwn(list, "keys")? ${Object.hasOwn(list, "keys")}`);
// => Object.hasOwn(list, "keys")? false
const listProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(list);
console.log(`listProto.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")? ${listProto.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")}`);
// => listProto.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")? true
console.log(`Object.hasOwn(listProto, "keys")? ${Object.hasOwn(listProto, "keys")}`);
// => Object.hasOwn(listProto, "keys")? true
```

---

Side note: That example assumes that `keys` is provided by the **imediate** prototype of `NodeList` (which it is on Chromium-based browsers). Here's a more general version that should work regardless of whether it's provided by the immediate prototype or something further up the chain:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll("*");
console.log(`list.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")? ${list.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")}`);
// => list.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")? false
console.log(`Object.hasOwn(list, "keys")? ${Object.hasOwn(list, "keys")}`);
// => Object.hasOwn(list, "keys")? false
let someProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(list);
while (someProto && !Object.hasOwn(someProto, "keys")) {
    someProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(someProto);
}
if (!someProto) {
    console.log("Huh?! Didn't find any object with `keys`");
} else {
    console.log(`someProto.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")? ${someProto.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")}`);
    // => someProto.propertyIsEnumerable("keys")? true
    console.log(`Object.hasOwn(someProto, "keys")? ${Object.hasOwn(someProto, "keys")}`);
    // => Object.hasOwn(someProto, "keys")? true
}
```

Comment: Isn't the Prototyp NodeList? I run it on the NodeList Object not on the nodelist itself.

Comment: @Kat - No, `NodeList` is a function, not the prototype of `NodeList` instances. The prototype of `NodeList` instances is `NodeList.prototype`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Kat - Just beware of assuming that `keys` comes *directly* from `NodeList.prototype`. As far as I'm aware, the actual hierarchy of `NodeList` is not specified (DOM defines it as an interface), so in theory it could be that `NodeList.prototype`'s prototype supplies `keys` (or even another layer above that). To be sure you're looking in the right place, cross-browser, see the example at the end of the answer -- you'll want to traverse the prototype chain.